# Remove rows that have a specific numeric value in a field

Tags: bash, unix, sed

I have a very bulky file about 1M lines like this:

```
4001    168991  11191   74554   60123   37667   125750  28474
8   145 25  101 83  51  124 43
2985    136287  4424    62832   50788   26847   89132   19184
3   129 14  101 88  61  83  32 1    14      10  12  7   13  4
6136    158525  14054   100072  134506  78254   146543  41638
1   40  4   14  19  10  35  4 
2981    112734  7708    54280   50701   33795   75774   19046
7762    339477  26805   148550  155464  119060  254938  59592
1   22  2   12  10  6   17  2 
6   136 16  118 184 85  112 56 1    28  1   5   18  25  40  2
1   26  2   19  28  6   18  3 
4071    122584  14031   69911   75930   52394   89733   30088
1   9   1   3   4   3   11  2 14    314 32  206 253 105 284 66
```

I want to remove rows that have a value less than 100 in the second column.

How to do this with sed?

Answer (score 6):

I would use awk to do this. Example:

```
awk ' $2 >= 100 ' file.txt
```

this will only display every row from file.txt that has a column `$2` greater than 100.

Comment: @EdMorton Right, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following approach:

```
sed '/^\w+\s+([0-9]{1,2}|[0][0-9]+)\b/d' -E /tmp/test.txt
```

(replace `/tmp/test.txt` with your current file path)

`([0-9]{1,2}|[0][0-9]+)` - will match either digits from `0` to `99` OR a digits with leading zero (ex. `012`, `00982`)

`d` - delete the pattern space;

`-E`(`--regexp-extended`) - Use extended regular expressions rather than basic regular expressions

---

To remove matched lines *in place* use `-i` option:

```
sed -i -E  '/^\w+\s+([0-9]{1,2}|[0][0-9]+)\b/d' /tmp/test.txt
```

Comment: probably `sed -nE '/^[0-9]+\s+0*[1-9][0-9]{2,}/p'` ? this will ignore leading zeros in second column but still get rows with 2nd column greater than or equal to 100... if 1st column can be other than digits, `\S+` would be better than `\w+`

Comment: @Sundeep, 1) as for `sed -nE '/^[0-9]+\s+0*[1-9][0-9]{2,}/p'` - yes, it could be an alternative; 
2) as for *\S+ would be better than \w+* - I don't think that it would be much better(according to performance aspect)

Comment: well I meant to convey it would match arbitrary characters than restricting to `\w` ... should have worded it better